# mysql 15 minutes from last entry selected

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Trying to only select entries from a table that are greater or equal to 15 minutes from last entry selected. I have tried the following but only get entries from 15 minutes on time. Example 09:00, 09:15, 09:30, etc...

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE  MINUTE(column) % 15 = 0;
```

The column is DATETIME.

Looking to find if the select entry was 09:02 then the next would be 09:17 or greater. But if the entry after that was 13:33 it wold select the entry after that which would be higher or equal to 13:48.

Thanks

UPDATE ON QUESTION: (04/10/18 3:15 central)

I have a table with a list in entries with a DATETIME column. I am looking to select and count rows where the DATETIME column is 15 minutes or greater apart on a specific user/account. So if user/account 1 had entries on 2018-01-06 04:47:11, 2018-01-06 04:47:59, 2018-01-06 04:49:11,2018-01-06 04:50:01, 2018-01-06 04:55:08, 2018-01-06 05:00:11, 2018-01-06 05:02:00, 2018-01-07 04:47:12, and 2018-01-07 05:05:11, it should only return a count of 3.

Comment: I think you're confusing what the modulus does.  When you have `% 15 = 0` you're asking for entries that are evenly divisible by `15`.

Comment: What do you mean by last entry? how do you get the time of the last entry?

Answer (score 2):

You may use that query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, column, last_entry_time) >= 15;
```

Provided that the query is built up so that `last_entry_time` is the datetime of what you call "*the last entry*"

Answer (score 1):

**Mixed solution**

May I suggest you to calculate the last 15 minutes and store it in a variable?

```
$minusfifteen = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-900);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table  WHERE  column >= $minusfifteen";
```

Be sure to change the datetime format I used to match yours, if so.

**SQL soltion**

pure mysql solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column >= DATE_SUB((SELECT MAX(column) FROM table), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Instead of separating the logic between two systems it's probably best to leave it up to the DBMS to achieve this. Something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTES)` could work, and is mentioned in the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: @adpro maybe I'm wrong, but the *last entry datetime* is not the current time. It's not clear from the OP question....

Comment: @adpro Yes it's even better I add your answer so the answer is more specific

Comment: @Paolo, I think you're right. Maybe this isn't a duplicate then.

Comment: Yes you're right it's a duplicated question. And as you point out @Paolo The last 15 minutes may refer to what happened yesterday

Comment: What we have to do is a diff between the last entry and 900 seconds. (I mean addition)

Comment: @Richard, sorry, I was wrong. My SQL won't solve his problem and the duplicate I added won't either. Proceed '-)

Comment: Check my edit to be sure I didn't made a mistake here

Comment: I would leave the answer the same as you had it before. It solved the problem I think. You have pure SQL below and your PHP/SQL mix. Both were valid and solved the problem, so you might as well include that instead of figuring out another way to do what the other answer is doing. But, you could put that top `select` as a subquery, though.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE ON QUESTION: (04/10/18 6:24 pm central)

This will return the results I am looking for, but would like a MySQL (non Mixed solution)

```
$checkTime = 0; // just to start
$count= 0;
$data = array();
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM table WHERE user='10' ORDER BY DateTimeColumn ";
$result = mysqli_query($db1,$sql);
while($rowData = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(strtotime($rowData['DateTimeColumn']) >= $checkTime) { // is it 15 or more minutes later
        $checkTime = strtotime($rowData['DateTimeColumn']) + 900; // add 15 minutes
        $count++;
        array_push($data, $rowData);
    }
}
```